# How is there an error with this code?

Tags: php, mysql, binary

I keep getting this error, I'm am very positive that my syntax is right!

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='00001010'' at line 1
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$decode = str_split($_POST['ascii'], 8);
mysql_connect("localhost","Username","Password");
mysql_select_db("information");
foreach($decode as $char){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ascii_binary WHERE binary='$char'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $char = $row['character'];
        echo $char;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `binary` is a reserved word and you need to wrap in backticks while using in query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BINARY` is reserved keyword in MySQL. Probably thats the reason of your error. So try to rename your column in MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use backticks around BINARY , because BINARY is reserved keyword for mysql.

like that:

```
 SELECT * FROM ascii_binary WHERE `binary` ='$char'
```